# Error while comparing two strings in python

Tags: python, string

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    score = 0
    tot = len(secretWord)
    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
       for j in range(len(lettersGuessed)):
           if (secretWord[i] == lettersGuessed[j]):
               score +=1
    if score == tot:
        return True 
    else:
         return False
```

For most of the words and guess letter m getting correct answer but while providing sceretWord as `mangosteen` and letter guessed as  `['z', 'x', 'q', 'm', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'o', 's', 't', 'e', 'e', 'n']` I am getting wrong output.

Any suggestions, why?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you could use:

```
set(secretWord).issubset(lettersGuessed)
```

to determine if guessed includes all of the letters in secret word.

Comment: Was just typing the same thing, +1 to you :)

Comment: well this is way indeed but i was trying not to use any string commands to perform this task , thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here is why:

There are two same character in `mangosteen`, `e`. Your code encountered it twice, so it adds two score. The total score of when `secretWord[i]` and `lettersGuessed[j]` is `e`, adds up to `4`.

Here is a solution:

You can simply use the `set` to check if every unique letters is there or not:

```
return all([True if i in set(g) else False for i in set(w)])
```

This makes the function much shorter :)

Demo:

```
>>> g = ['z', 'x', 'q', 'm', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'o', 's', 't', 'e', 'e', 'n']
>>> w = 'mangosteen'
>>> score = 0
>>> all([i for i in set(w) if i in set(g)])    
True
```

An alternative is to break the inner loop straight after you found the wanted letter:

```
if secretWord[i] == lettersGuessed[j]
    score +=1
    break
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i thought so but checking the value of score every time reveled that is getting incremented for every value it is encountering , and i am out of reason as of why it is happening

Comment: That's because the inner loop meet `e` twice for each `e` in the outer loop. Thus, the score is doubled.

Comment: thank alot mate  it seems breaking the for loop after encountering the condition solves the problem

Comment: That's very true! Once you meet the wanted char, you can just break the inner loop.

Comment: But this also fails: if the word is "mangosteen" and the guess is "mmangosten", the score will be 10.

Comment: Ah.. didn't realize that! Thanks for pointing it out. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Your all() in your current answer always returns True, because the list comprehension is either empty or consists of characters (which are True).

Comment: I must be sleepy tonight, fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My final answer should work with repeated characters, misguessed characters, etc. The key is that each character of the word should be removed from the list of guessed characters; if that fails, the character wasn't guessed (often enough) and we should return False.

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    guesses_left = list(lettersGuessed)
    for character in secretWord:
        try:
            guesses_left.remove(character)
        except ValueError:
            return False  # remove failed
    return True  # all characters succeeded
```

Comment: i am new to coding in python so no clue about try and except , i guess it is used for exception anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
lst = []
for e in lettersGuessed:
    if e in secretWord:
        lst.append(e)
if len(lst) == len(secretWord):
    return True
return False
```

I did this and it passed all cases.